# Error: cannot read property 'get' of undefined - HTTPS in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, https

I'm having an `app.js` which builds a `d3-Graph`. In this Graph there is a `Update-Button`. When the Button is clicked I want to call a function of another node.js file `data.js`.

```
Update-Button looks like this:

d3.select("#updatebutton").on("click", function(e) {
        try{
            getJSON();
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert('Error: ' + e);
        }
        window.parent.location = window.parent.location.href;
    });
```

If I click on `Update-Button` the Error is thrown:

> Error: cannot read property 'get' of undefined

The `get` is referred to an https request, performed in `data.js`.
Implemented as the following:

```
var https = require('https');
function getJSON() {
var req = https.get(options, function(response) {
    // handle the response
    var res_data = '';
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        res_data += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
        //do anything with received data
    });
});
req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
req.end();
```

}

If i run `data.js` on it's own (cmd: node data.js) it's working fine! So the https-Request itself is good. 
But if i call the `getJSON()` from the other file `app.js` I get the Error shown above.

How to fix this?

Comment: the HTTPS request is in the getJSON method so if you run data.js and no one is calling getJSON it doesnt mean the https Request itself is good.
The button click method is in the data.js or in app,js? can you please print e.stack and post it here?

Comment: The button click is in the app.js! How do i print e.stack? @GiladBison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var https = require('https'); function getJSON() {...}` is that code on the client-side?

I see that you are calling `getJSON();` from a client-side code, but it looks like the other code should be on the server-side, so you will need some sort of API to be called by the client-side code, and that API will return the results of the `function getJSON() {...}` function, so for example instead of the client-side call to `getJSON();`, it would be `$.get('/api/endpoint', function(data) { ... });`

---

**EDIT**

Here is an API sample using Express, so you need to add that into your `package.json` in the `dependencies` node > `"express": "~4.13.1",` and run `npm install` then `node app.js` assuming you put this code in `app.js` file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/api/data', function(req, res) {
  // you stuff goes here, getJSON function, etc
  // ...
  // ...

  var sample = {id: 5, name: 'test'};
  res.json(sample);
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

and your client side code will need to call that API, that could be done via jQuery for example like this

```
$.get('http://localhost:3000/api/data', function(data){
  // handle that 'data' on the client side here
  // ...
  // ...
});
```

Comment: I guess you are right with assuming that the call of getJSON() is on cient-side and data.js is on server-side. I have no idea though, how to implement "a sort of an API" in order to call that function getJSON() in data.js! @mkinawy

Comment: You have a lot of options to build a very basic RESTful API on Node.js, here is a list of some tutorials that could help you in that:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4

http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-create-rest-api

Comment: I watched on your links for the last 1.5 hours.... I have no idea on how to implement this in my example code.. could anyone help? @mkinawy

Comment: I will build you an API sample file in a minute